# como insertar valores de fecha en tabla mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema al insertar fechas en una columna de tabla `mysql`.

ya he probado con poner el campo como `varchar`, `date`, `datetime` y nada.

`$fecha_ant = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-3 day"));` // con esto obtengo la fecha actual - 3 dias, me devuelve la fecha correcta

Mi insert

```
$conn->exec("INSERT INTO tVentas (vendedor_id,fecha_trans,amount,tienda) VALUES($id_vendedor,$fecha_ant,$monto,0)");
```

al querer insertar este dato en `mysql` si el campo de `mysql` esta como `date` no inserta nada y si esta como `varchar` en vez de insertar la fecha, inserta un numero.

Por ejemplo si la fecha extraída es "2016-11-18", inserta "1987".

Leyendo al respecto, puede ser algo de la fecha `unix`, pero no estoy seguro. En la `DB` deseo insertar `2016-11-18` y no `1987`

Comment: Podrías añadir tu query mysql? De esa forma va a ser más sencillo ver si tienes un fallo en esa parte del proceso

Comment: Por favor, [edita](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/35049/edit) en vez de poner codigo en los comentarios

Comment: muchas gracias, soy nuevo en stackoverflow, y estaré frecuentemente por estos lados colaborando en lo que pueda! :) gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parece que estás intentando insertar la fecha sin comillas que escapen el valor.

```
$conn->exec("INSERT INTO tVentas (vendedor_id,fecha_trans,amount,tienda) VALUES($id_vendedor,$fecha_ant,$monto,0)");
```

Deberías intentar crear la query de la siguiente manera

```
$conn->exec("INSERT INTO tVentas (vendedor_id,fecha_trans,amount,tienda) VALUES($id_vendedor,'$fecha_ant', $monto, 0)");
```

De todas formas te recomiendo que utilices PDO para asegurar las queries que hagas a la base de datos.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tVentas (vendedor_id,fecha_trans,amount,tienda) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->execute([$id_vendedor, $fecha_ant, $monto, 0]);
```

Comment: muchas gracias!! me funcionó! llevaba 2 días peleando con esto! saludos!! tomaré en cuenta la recomendación

Answer (score 1):

La fecha aun que es de tipo Date al momento de pasarla ay que usar comillas como en tu ejemplo si metes los valores de manera directa

```
$fecha_ant = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-3 day"));
```

si te fijas en ese ejemplo estas usando comillas asi que intenta usarlas tambien en tus variables al momento de pasarlas en alguna query

Cambia esto $Fecha a esto '$Fecha' o "$Fecha"